# Save-As from MS Office ignores 'compressed' setting

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, ntfs, compression

I have my complete data hard disk compressed (the Windows NTFS standard functionality), including root, all directories, and all files.

When I open an Excel or Word file, and use Save-As, the new file is always *uncompressed*; I have to manually compress it afterwards. This happens on all machines I use; one Windows 7 with Office 2010; the second Windows XP with Office 2013; and when I save-as to a network-drive disk under Windows 10, the same thing happens.

All other programs (NotePad, or LightRoom, or PDF-printing, or whatever I try) save *compressed* - as they should - as this is the default of the directory, and I think applications shouldn't even *know* about compression on the file system level. It seems like Microsoft added special code in Office that bypasses parts of the NTFS file system and writes directly (and ignores the compressed-flag of the directory).

Any solutions for that?

Comment: I can't replicate the behavior with regularly updated Office 2013 64-bit on Windows 8.1. My suspicion was Office actually save the file on a temporary folder that somehow don't allow compression, then move the file to the destination folder, which would keep the compression flag off *if* it was on the same partition. But you've mentioned saving to a network drive, so it seems my suspicion is unfounded. Can you add some detail about your partition layout? Particularly if you're saving to different partition, cluster size. Also, are you on corporate network?

Comment: one of the machines is a company machine, the other not. For both, I tried saving to separate hard drives (*not* C:) and/or external (USB) hard drives; each has only one big partition. - your idea is interesting... but both machines the same issue? might be. Maybe I am always configuring something for my taste and that's the reason. I'll dig into that idea, thanks.

Comment: Try running Office on [safe mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-with-Office-safe-modes-76fd3b4c-7298-4b35-8b0e-1e2b68f76ab2) to check if it's because some errant add ons.

Comment: Good one (safe mode). That solves it. I know what to do from here on. Make it an answer, and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Office on [safe mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-with-Office-safe-modes-76fd3b4c-7298-4b35-8b0e-1e2b68f76ab2) (/safe) to eliminate the possibilities of errant add ons. Another possibilities will be if the files are saved on the same partition as Office & Windows system files, where the file is originally created on a temporary folder (which somehow disallow compression) and moved afterwards (moving on the same partition won't change compression and encryption flag).